# InvalidForeignKey: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "movies"

Tags: python, postgresql, error-handling

Two errors:

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique > constraint match ing given keys for referenced table "movies"

```
 [SQL: CREATE TABLE interested (
         id SERIAL NOT NULL,
         username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         title_id TEXT NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (id, username, title_id),
         UNIQUE (username),
         FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES "user" (username),
         FOREIGN KEY(title_id) REFERENCES movies (title) )
 
 ] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

and

> InvalidForeignKey: there is no unique constraint matching given
> keys for referenced table  "movies"

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

```
class Movies(db.Model):
"""Movies Table"""
__tablename__='movies'
title= db.Column(db.Text, 
                primary_key=True,
                 unique=True,
                 nullable=False
                 )
year= db.Column(db.Date, 
                nullable=False
                )
released=db.Column(db.Date, 
                   nullable=False
                   )
genre=db.Column(db.Text, 
                nullable=False
                )
writer=db.Column(db.Text, 
                 nullable=False
                 )
actors=db.Column(db.Text, 
                 nullable=False
                 )
plot=db.Column(db.Text, 
               nullable=False
               )
user_id= db.Column(db.Integer,
                   db.ForeignKey('users.id'))


class Interested(db.Model):
"""Movies User wants to watch"""
__tablename__='interested'
id=db.Column(db.Integer, 
             primary_key=True, 
             autoincrement=True
             )
username= db.Column(db.String(20),db.ForeignKey('user.username'), 
                    primary_key=True,
                    nullable=False, 
                    unique=True)
title_id= db.Column(db.Text,db.ForeignKey('movies.title'),  
                    primary_key=True,
                    nullable=False
                 )
```

Comment: Why are all fields in Interested primary keys?

Comment: I thought by making them primary keys it would stop the errors, I've been fiddling with this for two days now. I've researched foreign keys and it appears that I a missing something. I have three tables USER, MOVIES and INTERESTED. Interested  should have a foreign key from MOVIES and USER so I can add those to a playlist for a Movie Database that I am creating.

Comment: First, there can only be one PK for a table so your `Interested` model is invalid. Two, have you checked the `movies` table schema in `psql` using `\d movies`? I'm guessing it does not match the model.

Comment: what do you mean adrian?

Comment: I understand now. I removed the interested table and just have the movies and user table and it works fine, thanks!